# List returned from generic class in c# but list(covariant )is not getting updated in main class?

Tags: c#, generics

*c# code to return generic List from Class1*

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Class1<int> obj = new Class1<int>();
List<int> covariant = new List<int>();
covariant = obj.mark();
System.Console.WriteLine(covariant[0]);
}

   public class Class1<T>  
   {
       public List<T> mark()
       {
        List<object> covariant = new List<object>();
        covariant.Add(5);        *unable to get value in covariant list defined. Getting null vlaue*
        return covariant as List<T>;
       }
    }
```

*unable to get value in covariant list defined. Getting null vlaue*
*unable to get value in covariant list defined. Getting null vlaue*
*unable to get value in covariant list defined. Getting null vlaue*
*unable to get value in covariant list defined. Getting null vlaue*

Comment: `List<T>` is **not** covariant.

Comment: code is excecuted properly without error, but still list gettin null value.whats correct way to return list

Comment: As @JohnathanBarclaypointed out, you can't cast a `List<object>` to `List<int>`. Try `covariant as List<int>` and you'll get a CS0039 compile time error

Comment: @john `new List<T>` rather than `new List<object>`.

Comment: oh i got it.. Thanku guys for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not use `Generics` if you are going to explicitly use `int` inside your method.

This should be your first `hint` that you should not use generics in the first place.
Here is what your class might look like with a more proper use of generics.

```
public class Class1<T>
    {
        private List<T> covariants = new List<T>();

        public List<T> mark(T item)
        {
            covariants.Add(item);
            return covariants;
        }
    }
```

`var s = new Class1<int>.mark(5)` will return a list of count 1.
`s.mark(10)` will return a list with two items.

For more info about c# generics you can read the docs -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/